# Having to multiply geoms by number of facets?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I want to have multiple rectangles behind my data, but I also want to use multiple facets, every one of which these rectangles will appear in. I first ran the code below and got the error: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): fill`

Here's my code:

```
block_rects <- data.frame(xstart_rect=c(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5),
                          xend_rect=c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5))
df <- data.frame(xs=c(1,2,3),ys=c(1,2,3),cond=c("a","b","f"),fs=c("x","x","y"))
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=xs,y=ys,color=cond)) + 
  geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE,
            data = block_rects, aes(xmin = xstart_rect, xmax = xend_rect, 
                              ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            fill = c("#f1f1f1", "white","white","white","#f1f1f1","white")) +
    geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ fs)
```

However, I realized that when I **doubled** the number of items in the `fill` vector in `geom_rect`, it worked.  I worked out that I had to multiply the `fill` vector by the number of facets the plot has (e.g. if I change `fs` to `c("x","y","z")` I need to multiple the `fill` column by three).

**What the heck is up with that behavior?**  Is this a bug in the code?  If not, how should I make my code so that any number of facets can be used?  I don't want to have to explicitly code which variables are being faceted in `geom_rect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, you are drawing 12 rectangles (6 rectangles in each facet).  So ggplot expects either an overall fill color or a fill color identified for each of them.

An easier work-around than repeating the fill colors is to take advantage of aesthetic mapping by putting the fill colors for each rectangle into the rectangle data.frame.

```
block_rects <- data.frame(xstart_rect=c(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5),
                     xend_rect=c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5),
                     fill = c("#f1f1f1", "white","white","white","#f1f1f1","white"))
```

This allows you to map `fill` to a variable within the `aes` of `geom_rect`.  Use `scale_fill_identity` so it uses the given color names.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xs,y=ys,color=cond)) + 
    geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE,
            data = block_rects, aes(xmin = xstart_rect, xmax = xend_rect, 
                                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = fill)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ fs) +
    scale_fill_identity()
```

Comment: If you had other geoms that used different fills though, how would you use scale_fill_identity()?

Comment: You can only have one `fill` variable mapped, so this approach wouldn't work if you were already using `fill` for different variables.  If you have to write out the fill settings, you could always use `rep` on the vector with the number of unique values in your faceting variable as the number of times to repeat it.